# AJAX with a POST in a same page

Tags: php, ajax

I have page with a `POST` which `POST` 3 data . am i possible to access this data within da same page using `AJAX` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you have to do is a background page which the user won't ever see. That page is designed to speak with AJAX and nothing else.

You could probably make it possible using $_GET like mypage.php?ajax=true (would answer your request) and mypage.php?ajax=false would give the user the page contents.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use..but i suggest to use

[jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for your purpose...

> This method is the simplest way to
>   fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data,
>   success)